# Error in getting OAuth authentication url

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, appharbor, httplib2

I have the following code in a Python desktop application that authorizes users before using the AppHarbor API. I am following the steps mentioned in the [knowledge base](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/api/oauth-v2) and have the following authentication code:

```
 def OnAuthenticate(self, event):
    client_id = "" # My App's client id
    client_secret_key = "" # My App's secret key
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=client_id, secret=client_secret_key)

    request_token_url = "https://appharbor.com/user/authorizations/new?client_id="+client_id+"&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8095"

    client = oauth2.Client( consumer )
    resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
    ...
```

However, on sending the request, the response is incorrect, this is the error:

```
client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not None
```

Is there something that I am missing here?

---

Edit: Following is the stack trace that is thrown up:

```
    resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
    File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg\oauth2\__init__.py", line 682, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2-0.7.4-py2.7.egg\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1544, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2-0.7.4-py2.7.egg\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1342, in _request
   (response, content) = self.request(location, redirect_method, body=body, headers = headers, redirections = redirections - 1)
    File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg\oauth2\__init__.py", line 662, in request
    req.sign_request(self.method, self.consumer, self.token)
    File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg\oauth2\__init__.py", line 493, in sign_request
    self['oauth_body_hash'] = base64.b64encode(sha(self.body).digest())
    TypeError: must be string or buffer, not None
```

Upon debugging into the call, I reached httplib2._request function that issued a request

```
(response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
```

This resulted in the following page with error response = 302 (presented in content object)

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://appharbor.com/session/new?returnUrl=%2Fuser%
 2Fauthorizations%2Fnew%3Foauth_body_hash%3D2jmj7l5rSw0yVb%252FvlWAYkK%252FYBwk%
 253D%26oauth_nonce%3D85804131%26oauth_timestamp%3D1340873274%
 26oauth_consumer_key%3D26bacb38-ce5a-4699-9342-8e496c16dc49%26oauth_signature_method%
 3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%
 253A8095%26client_id%3D26bacb38-ce5a-4699-9342-8e496c16dc49%26oauth_signature%
 3DXQtYvWIsvML9ZM6Wfs1Wp%252Fy3No8%253D">here</a>.</h2>
 </body></html>
```

The function next removed the body from the content to call another request with body set to None, resulting in the error that was thrown.

```
(response, content) = self.request(location, redirect_method, body=body, headers = headers, redirections = redirections - 1)
```

Comment: You should have a traceback with the exact file and line where the exception is raised, as well as the full call stack. Maybe you could post it ? (or even read it, chances here it will answer your question).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Python lib, but have you considered whether this is because you need to take the user through the [three-legged flow Twitter flow](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) and use the url you mention in your question as the authorize_url? Once you have the code, you retrieve the token by POST'ing to this url: `https://appharbor.com/tokens`.

You might also want to take a closer look at the [desktop OAuth .NET sample](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/06/21/oauth-for-net-desktop-applications) to get a better understanding of how this works.